# window.onload -> addEventListener to button?

Tags: javascript, events, syntax, event-listener

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>

    <button id="myid">clickme</button>
    <script>
        window.onLoad = function () {
            document.getElementById('myid').addEventListener('click', () => {
                console.log('clicked');
            });
        };
    </script>
</html>
```

I tried around with couple things that all should alledgedly work but dont get whats wrong
Why does it not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with `window.onload`.  There is no caps in the `onload` property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('myid').addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log('clicked');
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="myid">clickme</button>
```